# How do I have a meaningful error message from powershell script running in TeamCity build?

Tags: powershell, error-handling, build, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have a TeamCity build and one of the steps is an MSBuild invokation of a .proj file:

```
Runner type: MSBuild
Build file path: TestProject.proj
Targets: Test
```

inside the .proj I have targets:

```
<Target Name="DeployTestService">
    <Message Text="Deploying test service" />
    <Exec Command="powershell -Command &quot;&amp; { myUsefulPsScript.ps }&quot;" />
</Target>

<Target Name="Test">
   // other stuff, then
   <CallTarget Targets="DeployTestService" />
</Target>
```

and it works good most of the time. Yet if the powershell script fails (an unhandled exception is thrown and I can see its text in the full log) and exits with non-zero code I see the following in Teamcity build results:

```
 Tests passed: (some number); exit code 1
```

and the build tree just says:

```
Build failure condition (1)
 Process exited with code 1   
   [Time]Process exited with code 1
```

and until I get the full log I don't really know which step failed and how exactly. It's not about fixing the initial problem it's about locating the faulty step faster.

Is there a way to make Teamcity say something like "runner in step N failed with this error message [message which I see in the full log]"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Teamcity output format](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity). For example, every time a new test starts, print:

```
##teamcity[testStarted name='foo|'s test']
```

This way Teamcity will know what was the last step or the last test before the app crashed and it will be able to format the output accordingly.